# PrimeFaces 3.5 - DataTable - NPE on column remove after manual sort

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

Our datatables have dynamic columns and are sortable. User can add and remove columns. Overall it is working well except in one scenario. There is a NullPointerException when user sorts data in the table w.r.t to the last column in the table and then removes that last column. If the column is not last then there is no problem at all.

Following is the stacktrace. Any clues if/how it can be fixed.

```
[#|2017-04-20T14:02:59.021+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application|_ThreadID=119;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Error Rendering View[/view/instrumentmgmt/instrumentManager.xhtml]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.findColumn(DataTable.java:711)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.SortFeature.singleSort(SortFeature.java:124)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.preRender(DataTableRenderer.java:99)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:80)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:877)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1826)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:543)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:683)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1663)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1663)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1663)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1663)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1663)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1663)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1663)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:383)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:302)
    at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:183)
    at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:183)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:973)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1819)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:421)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.application.PrettyViewHandler.renderView(PrettyViewHandler.java:163)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:286)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:286)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:286)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
```

Comment: With a newer version? And please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: It sounds like a bug on Primefaces table